# Formula behind tikz's `to [out=, in=]` curve

Tags: tex-core, tikz-pgf

In the section 14.13 in [Tikz manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), they define a parametric curve function like `\draw $node1 to [out=90, in=180] $node2`. An example from the PDF is like [image]

**My question is : what kind of mathematical formula is behind of this curve?**

My first guess was that it draws a 3-point Bezier curve whose control point is the cross point of the two lines defined by `out=` and `in=` parameter, but it appears wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can always ask Ti*k*Z to show us how they are doing things. One tool is the `show path construction` decoration, see p. 645 of pgfmanual v3.1.5

[image]

I copied the `curveto` part and adjusted it to the question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{how does TikZ do that/.style={postaction=decorate,
decoration={show path construction, 
moveto code={},
lineto code={},
curveto code={
\draw [green!75!black,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);
\draw[red,dashed] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) node[dot,label=above left:start]{}
 -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)  node[dot,label=above left:first control]{};
\draw[red,dashed] (\tikzinputsegmentlast) node[dot,label=above right:target]{}
 -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)  node[dot,label=above:second control]{};
},
closepath code={},
}},dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[how does TikZ do that] (0,0) to[out=90,in=180] (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So we see that this is just a cubic Bezier curve where the control point are chosen according to the slope. You can change the lengths of the dashed lines, i.e. the distance of the control points from start and target, respectively, by changing the looseness. Try e.g.

```
\draw[how does TikZ do that] (0,0) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1.5] (3,2);
```

[image]

One can change the `in looseness` and `out looseness` separately. They control the lengths of the respective dashed lines.

The technical details, i.e. the underlying code, can be found in `tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex`, a library that gets automatically loaded.

In general, as is suggested by the `show path construction` decoration, a single path is one of the following:

1. move to,
2. line to,
3. curve to,
4. close path.

The `curve to` path is either a cubic or quadratic Bezier curve, where the quadratic can be seen as special case of the cubic one. A possible parametrization of cubic Bezier curves can be found in equation (1) in section **46.2 Computing the Bounding Box** on p. 581 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

[image]